# react-native-material-textfield Doesn't work as a controlled input

Tags: react-native, textfield, controlled-component

I'm using "react-native-material-textfield" for text inputs. I have a View to edit user details it fetch values from api when mounting and set it to state. But after upgrading "react-native-material-textfield" to "0.16.1" that original first name value is not shown in the text input after mounting. What I'm doing wrong here ?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
    
    };
  }
```

```
componentDidMount(props) {
   APIcall().then(data)=>{
    this.setState({
      firstName: data.firstName
    });
  }
}
```

```
<TextField
              label="First Name"
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChangeText={firstName => this.setState({firstName})}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this after upgrading. In version `0.13.0` of the library, it [switched to being a fully uncontrolled component](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield/releases/tag/0.13.0) according to the release notes.

> **Changed**
>
> - `defaultValue` prop becomes current value on focus
> - `value` prop provides only initial value

Based on the current [usage docs](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield#usage), there is now a method exposed for setting & getting the value using a ref to the component:

```
let { current: field } = this.fieldRef;

console.log(field.value());
```

(Personally, while I can maybe understand this improving performance because typing can often be fast for state updates, I'm not a fan of uncontrolled components since I want my state to drive the UI. I feel like this makes other live updates for validation very fiddly.)

Comment: I used `onLayout={this.loadMyInitialValue}` in the TextField object as it is called upon the component is rendered the first time.

Answer (score 0):

In react-native-material-textfield, 'value' prop acts as default. To update the value you need to use ref. Get the ref using React.createRef(), then use setValue function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextField } from 'react-native-material-textfield';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class TestComponent extends Component {
  textField = React.createRef<TextField>();
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'check',
    };
  }

  onChangeText = () => {
    // Send request via API to save the value in DB
  };

  updateText = () => {
    if (this.textField && this.textField.current) {
      this.textField.current.setValue('test');
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextField
          label="Test value"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
          ref={this.textField}
        />
        <Button onPress={this.updateText} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Touch area in TextView
```

https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield/issues/248

```
    react-native-material-textfield 
    
    labelTextStyle={{ position: 'absolute', left: '100%' }}
    
     label: {
        fontFamily: fonts.Muli_SemiBold,
        fontSize: 14,
        letterSpacing: 0.1,
            color: colors.gray90,
            position: 'absolute', left: '100%'
      },

 <TextField
    style={style.textInputRight}
    labelTextStyle={style.label}
    labelFontSize={16}}
    onChangeText={value => onTextChange(value)}
                />
```